# How can I print all links within a found elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to **BeautifulSoup**, I found all the cards, about 12. But when I'm trying to loop through each card and print link href. I kept getting this error

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'up-card-section'})

# print(cards)
print(len(cards))

for link in cards.find_all('a'):
     print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Could you give us an example html?

Comment: They're too long, but here : https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/OWVhYzBlYzMtMjA0NS00ZjU5LThlMWUtNjNjODkyOGNmMzhk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cards = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'up-card-section'})
```

Will return a collection of all the `div`'s found, you'll need to loop over them before finding the chil `a`'s.

That said, you should probably use `findChildren` for finding the `a` elements.

---

Example Demo with an minimal piece of HTML

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class='up-card-section'>
    <div class='foo'>
        <a href='example.com'>FooBar</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='up-card-section'>
    <div class='foo'>
        <a href='example2.com'>FooBar</a>
    </div>
</div>
"""

res = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for card in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'up-card-section'}):
    for link in card.findChildren('a', recursive=True):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
example.com
example2.com
```

Comment: No error, but it doesn't seem to print anything. Can you verify your codes with my HTML ? Is it possible to run online somewhere in the fiddle ?

https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/OWVhYzBlYzMtMjA0NS00ZjU5LThlMWUtNjNjODkyOGNmMzhk

Comment: Im looking for an `a` inside an `up-card-section`, but can;t find it. Can you please show a minimal piece of html?

Comment: I don't know how to do that because it is the source from a link from one of my Upwork Post. By us doing `card in cards` it should only focus on one card... right?

Comment: I;ve made an minimal example, recommend using findChildren over find_all.